# if-then-else condition in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, web-mapping, raster-calculator, rtree

I have Sample RGB combination from 3 different Bands

[image: RGB Imagery composite from 3 diferent band combination]

```
// Input RGB imagery
var image = ee.Image("users/k2yulianto/Exercise/Ras/Imagery");
// Use Tree bands from RGB Imagery
var bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
var b1 = ['b1'];
var b2 = ['b2'];
var b3 = ['b3'];
// Display the inputs imagery
Map.addLayer (image, {bands: ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], max: 1, gamma:1, opacity:0.80} , 'RGB imagery',true);
Map.setCenter (101.4476, 0.4925, 12);
```

[image: Sampling point distribution]

And I have also sampling point distribution on top of RGB Imagery.

```
// Sampling point on top of RGB imagery to identify 4 diferent class
var Sampling = ee.FeatureCollection("users/k2yulianto/Exercise/Sampling/Sampling");
Map.addLayer (Sampling, {opacity:0.80},'Sampling point', true);
```

Based on the sampling point, I am to produce decision tree using WEKA to distinguish the type of class on RGB imagery.

[image: WEKA Decision tree]

```
//var exercise = ee.Algorithms.if(condition,truecase,falsecase)
var exercise = ee.Algorithms.If(b2 <= (0),(ee.Algorithms.If(b3 <= (0),"Sample 1","Sample 2")),(ee.Algorithms.If(b1 <= (0),"Sample 3","Sample 4")));
print('Imagery output: ',exercise);
```

I want to display if-then-else condition into an image classification.

```
// Display the 4 Class exercise output imagery
var RGBPalette = 
['#5f932c', // Class 01
'#bdff09', // Class 02 
'#fdf613', // Class 03 
'#abfffb', // Class 04
];
Map.addLayer(exercise,{min: 0, max: 4, palette: RGBPalette}, 'Exercise imagery');
```

After I run the scripts, I got an error warning:

> Cannot add an object of type  to the map.

Here is my full code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/77b2238d1a628c59dfa440a27adfa378

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `arcgis-desktop`?

Comment: In arcgis destop i am already solved this problem trought raster calculator (if than else), i write it in Google Earth engine similar formula, but not work.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ArcGIS, and therefore shouldn't be tagged with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are using to solve the problem (`ee.Algorithms.If`) is for using an `if` statement inside a GEE loop (`map` or `iterate`), but not for this case.

For this, there are a couple of ways to do it, but I think the easier would be using the `expression` function:

```
var exercise = image.expression('b(1)<=0 ? (b(2)<=0 ? 1 : 2) : (b(0)<=0 ? 3 : 4)').rename('class')
```

Inside parenthesis you can use the number of the band, like in this example `b(1)` is band `b2`, or you could use the name `b("b2")` (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_math)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/708bfe3d64299bc0982390f0047be9ad

Comment: i have one more question. in class 4 have same classify with "no Data" . can i have other class as no data (except class 1-4) become transparent (or if "no data" will not be classify?). .. Thanks for your help

Comment: Add this line `exercise = exercise.updateMask(image.select(0).mask())`. If the answer is what you were looking for you can mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help Rodrigo E. Principle  .... Now work and is correct.. ready to applied in the real complex's decision tree algorithms

Comment: @KokokYulianto Please consider clicking the green accept checkmark next to whichever answer to each of your questions helps you the most.  That way you both acknowledge and reward the efforts of our answerers who volunteer their time here.